# Website wrapped in iOS App - Catching hyperlink click events

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a iOS app that wraps a website.  When the user clicks a link in the wrapped website, I want to trap the event in my app and be able to get information about the link that was clicked.  Is this something that can be done in Swift?

I'm relatively new to iOS app development and I'm working on an app that has been around for a while.

Comment: Are you using a `WKWebView`? There should be delegate methods to detect new URLs to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".  There are a couple of views that you can use in iOS to display web content.  One such view is [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

If you look at the documentation at that link, close to the bottom of the page you will find a header for "Managing Navigation Through your Web Content".

What you do is create a `WKNavigationDelegate` that you attach to your `WKWebView`.  That delegate is notified when the user wants to navigate through the web content (for example, when they click on a link) and lets your application code participate in the navigation process.  It can allow navigation, deny navigation, find out when it starts and stop, things of that nature.